# HML Div Positioning

Tags: html, css, layout

How can I get the main box to sit in the middle of all of the elements?  It is currently sitting below the #1 box and I want it smack in the middle, slid in below the menu.  I know this is extremely basic stuff, but I'm kinda stuck.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
<div group="menu">
    <div id="menu1">#1</div>
    <div id="menu2">#2</div>
    <div id="menu3">#3</div>
    <div id="menu4">#4</div>
    <div id="menu4">#5</div>
    <div id="settings">Settings</div>
    <div id="main">Main</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
    width: 1330px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;

}

h1{
    font-size: 500%;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #9DC8C3;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    text-align: center;
}


/*menus */

#menu1{
    width:211px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#menu2{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#menu3{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#menu4{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#menu5{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#settings{
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#main{
    width:700px;
    height:400px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code for you. What I did was that I added a div that plays a container roll and a table to keep the settings div on the right side and rest of the divs on the left side.

Here's the HTML part:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">    
    <div id="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
    <div group="menu" class="menu-group">
    <div id="menu1">#1</div>
    <div id="menu2">#2</div>
    <div id="menu3">#3</div>
    <div id="menu4">#4</div>
    <div id="menu5">#5</div>
    <div id="main">Main</div> 
    </div> 
            <td>
    <div id="settings">Settings</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS part:

```
.container {
    width: 1330px;
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;

}

h1{
    font-size: 500%;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #9DC8C3;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    text-align: center;
}


/*menus */

#menu1{
    width:211px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#menu2{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#menu3{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#menu4{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#menu5{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#settings{
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;

}

#main{
    width:700px;
    height:400px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin:5px;
}
```

And also here's a little example of what I did:

https://jsfiddle.net/5tjp8sc8/2/

Answer (score 1):

You should put the div with class `main` before the `settings` div.

```css
#header{
    width: 1330px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;

}

h1{
    font-size: 500%;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #9DC8C3;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    text-align: center;
}


/*menus */

#menu1{
    width:211px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#menu2{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#menu3{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#menu4{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#menu5{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#settings{
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#main{
    width:700px;
    height:400px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
<div group="menu">
    <div id="menu1">#1</div>
    <div id="menu2">#2</div>
    <div id="menu3">#3</div>
    <div id="menu4">#4</div>
    <div id="menu4">#5</div>
    <div id="main">Main</div>
    <div id="settings">Settings</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Knew it would be something simple.